# How to delete tmp files with messy names?

Tags: shell, rm

By mistake, I created a lot of tmp files suffix '.bedgraph' in my working directory. How could I delete them? I tried to use `rm -rf *.bedgraph` but it did not work.

```
MBD_peak_bedfile
N?????A???c??XO.bedgraph
N8??-?X???X?g.??<?=Ԓ????p???<?zʴ?9?JO:J??????iưUl??d>?.bedgraph
N[????n??v?2|z?F7,?ܧ?????g9d.m#??R??.bedgraph
Nq???)???qgV{?hz`?????K,?.bedgraph
Nq??(JBv?D???L???lo??"??8????w??U"?[???*?Q??????Ј???R????;u?c<?s???}`>??=?Ft???h^???S???}??EP??!AdC??J?]?`.bedgraph
Oդ?k.bedgraph
O?m|?t)???¶?j????ci?O???"?F??J?,???*??????%??????ֳ?^?6??{v}3D?4??Ek??c3l??Hw?????+{???&?ۙ6???a?????BM;,fi?(_???????n??@`?.bedgraph
O9???n???t???܁?і??V7??.bedgraph
OC}?U?Q???.bedgraph
OEbѻh?_?Ri_?~???ׂ???-i:?6խtq?&?.bedgraph
On????(???,?ݶ5??-Ֆ?????Ҫ'?$??????S-??<M???(??՛??.bedgraph
O|?i?U?ֽ???oo???vK?????~w?Yڄ[????S"??A?ۃ??????U??؉??F?????????Ʋ1?3$???P?Lg?????x,&?Q?????.bedgraph
Oű??4?"?DI&?OE?Mp?????M??#r%?O?????????!?@~????p???K????9̡?L??z??E?㰹???????-???^?.bedgraph
P?+?g?+ԟm(??ֆ.bedgraph
P?;?}=9??.bedgraph
P?H?????v??$?Y^d?h?'?.,?S??cEٴ??.bedgraph
P.bedgraph
PeakSplitter_Cpp
PeakSplitter_Cpp_1.0.tar.gz
...
```

I could just ignore those tmp files, but they make the directory really messy.

Comment: you want to delete only those files which has `bedgraph` in their name ?

Comment: did you use `rm -- "*.bedgraph"`?

Comment: @Rahul. Except one named "TFChIP_tCD25input.sort.bedgraph"

Comment: rename the good one to `TFChIP_tCD25input.sort.bedgraph.GOOD` then get rid of the bad "*.bedgraph" files, I suggest by moving them to a temporary directory first, then `rm -rf` the directory when you're sure.  Afterwards rename your good file back to its former name

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.bedgraph' -delete
```

should work.

Be careful not to delete anything inadvertently.

Comment: Run with `--print` instead of `--delete` first (or just delete `--delete`) to see if the right files are selected.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for explaining my last sentence.

Comment: @PSkocik. Yes, it worked. Also it was the exact reason why "rm" did not work. what if I want to exempt one file name "donotwannadelete.bedgraph" from deletion?

Comment: @Jun use `find ! -name 'donotwannadelete.bedgraph' ..`

Comment: @Rahul. I see, TKS!